# How to check established domains in linux

Tags: linux, networking, dns

My aim is to check if a domain is being accessed from a system running Linux, and if it is being accessed, I need to run a command.

I have accomplished this using crontab. I have written a little script where if a domain is being accessed, say 'https://www.youtube.com/', I run a command to send a notification to the user on the system, and this script is run every minute using cron. This is mainly for parental control. I have everything figured out except for the part where we see if a domain is being accessed. I tried reading the `netstat` command documentation but I couldn't find anything there. I just need a command which can check if a specific website/domain is being accessed at that particular second. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `netstat | grep '^tcp.*www.youtube.com'`

Comment: @Barmar That command returns nothing even when youtube is actively running :(

Comment: Youtube probably uses a CDN service, and the actual streaming goes to the domain of the CDN, not youtube.com.

Comment: for reference, here's the output for `netstat` when youtube is loading the home page in a browser: https://pastebin.com/EPJYwtTX

Comment: @Barmar I do not have much knowledge on this topic but as I understand, there is no way to tell if youtube is being accessed via netstat?

Comment: Browsers don't keep the connection open, so it's really hard to catch it.

Comment: You're better off using parental controls in the browser, this is really tricky to do with external monitoring.

Comment: You can try `netstat -n` and do a reverse lookup of the IPs, but as it was mentioned that's tricky and unreliable. Also take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls